# agregar contenido a hipervínculos por defecto distinto a los visitados

Tags: css

Hola amigos estoy utilizando la extensión stylebot que permite editar o agregar CSS para las paginas web:

como lo dice la publicación estoy tratando de `agregar contenido a hipervínculos por defecto distinto a los visitados`.

Esto lo estoy haciendo con CSS:

```css
a.question-hyperlink {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
}


a.question-hyperlink {
  color: #c27ba0;
}

a.question-hyperlink::before {
  content: "[New] -> ";
}

a.question-hyperlink:visited {
  color: #f6b26b;
}

a.question-hyperlink:visited::before {
  content: "[Rev] -> ";
}
```

pero no estoy obteniendo el resultado esperado ya que los link visitados; sigue apareciéndome el contenido agregado a los por defecto `[New] ->`  y no este `[Rev] ->` que seria el contenido esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se puede: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

---

Los estilos definidos por la pseudo-clase `:visited` serán anulados por cualquier pseudo-clase posterior relacionada con el enlace (`:link`, `:hover` o `:active`) que tenga al menos la misma especificidad. Para darle un estilo apropiado a los enlaces, coloque la regla `:visited` después de la regla `:link` pero antes de las reglas `:hover` y `:active`, según lo definido por el orden `LVHA`: `:link` — `:visited` — `:hover` — :`active`.

## Restricciones de estilo

> Por motivos de privacidad, los navegadores limitan estrictamente los estilos que puede aplicar utilizando esta pseudo-clase y cómo se pueden usar:

> Las propiedades CSS permitidas son `color`, `background-color`, `border-color`, `border-bottom-color`, `border-left-color`, `border-right-color` (en-US), `border-top-color`, `column-rule-color` (en-US), y `outline-color`.
> Los atributos SVG permitidos son `fill` (en-US) y `stroke` (en-US).
> El componente alfa de los estilos permitidos será ignorado. En su lugar, se utilizará el componente alfa del estado `non-:visited` del elemento, excepto cuando ese componente sea 0, en cuyo caso el estilo establecido en `:visited` se ignorará por completo.
> Aunque estos estilos pueden cambiar la apariencia de los colores para el usuario final, el método `window.getComputedStyle` mentirá y siempre devolverá el valor del color `non-:visited`.
> Nota: Para obtener más información sobre estas limitaciones y las razones detrás de ellas, vea Privacidad y el selector `:visited` (en-US).

[vea Privacidad y el selector `:visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector)